# Calculating angle of HSL value from an annulus colorspace

Tags: math, colors, imagemagick

The following ImageMagick commands created the image shown:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc: \
        -fx 'aa=atan2(j-h/2+.5,i-w/2+.5)/pi/2; aa>0 ? aa : aa+1' \
        hue_angular.png

convert -size 100x100 xc:black \
        -fill white  -draw 'circle 49.5,49.5 40,4' \
        -fill black  -draw 'circle 49.5,49.5 40,30' \
        -alpha copy -channel A -morphology dilate diamond anulus.png

convert hue_angular.png -size 100x100 xc:white xc:gray50 \ 
        -combine -set colorspace HSL -colorspace RGB \
        anulus.png -alpha off -compose Multiply -composite \
        anulus.png -alpha on  -compose DstIn -composite \
        -colorspace sRGB hues_HSL.png
```

[image: HSV Annulus]

I am looking for 2 formulas.

The first one would calculate HSL values given an angle *a*.

The second would calculate the closest angle *a* to a given HSL value.

I could do this by extracting the HSL values (one for each degree) from a larger image and using this for a lookup table or calculating distance, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

NOTE: The image would not be available for use in any code, it is only there to show the colorspace. In the image red is at 0 degrees, green at 120 and blue at 240 degrees.

Comment: In the 3rd command, you use the calculated Hue and set the Saturation to 100% (`xc:white`) and Lightness to 50% (`xc:gray`), so your Saturation and Lightness are constant and independent of the angle. So the HSL value at any angle is surely going to be `hsl(a,100%,50%)`? Or maybe `hsl(a*255/360, 100%, 50%)` depending how you want it scaled.

Comment: Does it have to be HSL? It's a truly horrible colorspace. If you are able to consider alternatives, LCh (the polar version of CIELAB) is much simpler and much better behaved. I realize this may not be a helpful comment :( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_color_space

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for that. I didn't know enough of about colorspace or ImageMagick to realise that H is the angle. That will makes things very easy. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @jcupitt: HSL is not so bad, and it is used natively in e.g. CSS,so very handy to mangle colours, is a much more sensible way compared to RGB. [CSS and like: so design view, so related and complement colours]. I appreciate the green on bottom part (anticlockwise), not seldom seen, but, IIRC, Munsell used it (the origin of all modern colour spaces).

Comment: LCh is actually closer to Munsell than HSL, interestingly. You're right, of course, that if your aim is to represent the RGB cube in polar form then HSL is what you're stuck with. But if you have a choice (one often does not) and want a sane colorspace to work with, LCh is /much/ better.

Comment: @jcupitt It is for an RGBW smart bulb. The generated color wheel perfectly matches the one in the control app for the bulb and it sends the color to the bulb as an HSL angle. If I'm going to take over control of it then I will need to use HSL.

Comment: Ah I wasn't sure what your aim was. Sure, HSL sounds very reasonable in your case. Though of course the colour in your app won't be a great match for the colour of the bulb, but that's a different problem!